# Border not appearing continuous

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am trying to make an arc using border-radius like this (in chrome)

```css
#elem {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: none;

  width: 440px;
  height: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 220px 60px;
  border-top-left-radius: 222px 60px;
}
```

but the arc is not continuous. if i remove the border-bottom property (which makes the bottom border also visible) it became continous. Making bottom-border color to transparent also doesn't help.

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/kFxec/9/

Not able to understand what is wrong here?

I am trying this for chrome only. works fine in firefox

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with your height. If I up the height to 90px, it's fine. Does your box need to only be 60px high?

Comment: or u can cheat like this http://jsfiddle.net/kFxec/6/ :)

Comment: it also works for small widths but actually in my case, the width/height is not static and i am assigning the border radius dynamically according to the width and height. like horizontal radius 50% of width and verticall radius is 100% of height. updated the question with correct value for width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it is some kind of bug.
Seems related to the bottom border.
It disappears with this CSS

```
#elem {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: none;

  width: 440px;
  height: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 220px 60px;
  border-top-left-radius: 222px 60px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
```

What you see cutting the top border seems the bottom border doing strange things around. But giving it a moderate radius seems to somehow make it behave. (I don't know why)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFxec/15/)

Answer (score 5):

you could instead fake border with box-shadow : http://jsfiddle.net/ZC2m2/

```
#elem {
  box-shadow:0 -2px 0  orange;
  width: 440px;
  height: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 220px 60px;
  border-top-left-radius: 222px 60px;
}
```

Comment: this workaround is awesome but unfortunately in our product we are actually using dotted border style. i had written this e.g. to find out what is wrong. may be its a browser bug than i should go with your solution.